# Differences between nxml-mode and nxhtml-mode?

Tags: emacs, nxhtml, nxml

I installed `nxml-mode` and then `nxhtml-mode` (and they look great, real-time validation right inside my favorite editor is just sweet).

I understand that an XHTML file is an XML file and so I can use "just" `nxml-mode` to edit the XHTML.  But I'm a bit confused: what does `nxhtml-mode` offer that `nxml-mode` does not?

If you were to edit XHTML, would you simply use `nxml-mode` or would you take the time to also install `nxhtml-mode`?

**EDIT** I've *of course* read the first page of nxhtml, where I downloaded nxhtml.

It says this, for example:

```
Completion and syntax checking for XHTML
```

So what kind of completion, for example, does it do that nxml-mode wouldn't do?

An example of something that can be done with nxhtml and that cannot be done with nxml would be really great.

Comment: as a comment: the first link if you Google on "differences between nxml-mode and nxhtml-mode" links to this SO question.  Maybe questions without answers should *NOT* be referenced by Google and should only start referencing once there's at least one comment (or one answer).    ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nXhtml [homepage](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) discusses exactly this in the first section.

When I tried to use nXhtml, the reason was mumamo, which is only included in nXhtml.  I needed a mult-mode solution for Rails development.  It turned out that it made Emacs too laggy and didn't work perfectly all the time.  I gave up after a few weeks.  I never tried the completion stuff.

Comment: I've read this: this is where I d/l'ed nxhtml-mode from.  It's still not very clear, see my edit.  Moreover that link will very probably become broken at one point or another, so a few infos here would be a good addition to SO...